# AMD Overdrive Triangle Artifacts all over screen

Tags: windows-7, overclocking, amd-catalyst

I was in AMD Catalyst Control Centre (CCC) and saw the AMD Overdrive function so me thinking this could cause no harm I messed with the settings. I didn't put the settings up high at all. I then click apply. Everything seemed fine. I then opened World of Warcraft.

Right when I did that I got red triangles all over and my screen froze. I panicked and shut my computer down. I then restarted it normally. Everything seemed normal again. I then opened CCC again. Right when I did that all the triangles appeared again. I then restarted and open CCC again I got in and turned the settings down.

I opened World of Warcraft again. It froze but then unfroze but I lost my cursor. I haven't messed with my computer anymore. I'm too afraid. Imagine its lagging because I turned the settings ALL the way down. Maybe I should just reinstall the driver? I'm pretty sure no hardware is damaged or my computer would crash as soon as I opened a program.

Comment: Your message is a bit hard to understand. Please tell what your computer is, what operating system you run, and what you mean by CCC, and what you did with AMD Overdrive. Without exact details, it is unlikely somebody will be able to diagnose your problem.

Comment: CCC= catalyst control center windows 7 HP Slimline. Overdrive is AMD version of overclocking.

Answer (score 0):

### Boot into safe mode

1. Immediately after the computer is powered on or restarted (usually
   after you hear your computer beep), tap the F8 key in 1 second
   intervals.
2. After your computer displays hardware information and runs a memory
   test, the Advanced Boot Options menu will appear.

### Uninstall your current graphics driver

1. Click on Start.
2. Open the Control Panel.
3. Select Add or Remove Programs.
4. From the list of currently installed programs, select AMD Catalyst
   Install Manager.
5. Select Change and continue with the uninstallation steps.
6. Restart the system.

### Download and install the latest non-beta driver for your card

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/catalyst-windows-install.aspx

### Test to see if it works

Download FurMark and run a GPU stress test ( [tutorial here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/100356-video-card-stress-test-furmark.html) ). If the problem persists, your issue is most likely faulty hardware (GPU [most likely], cable [very much less likely], or monitor [almost impossible]). To determine if the GPU itself is faulty, find another machine or a friend's machine to test the GPU in. Run the same FurMark application on the same operating system for the most accurate result.